# Confusion between self and super in a subclass

Tags: ios, swift, class, oop, inheritance

Let's say you have a class named `Vehicle`:

```swift
class Vehicle {
    var name: String
    var size: Int
    
    init(name: String, size: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
    }
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init(name: name, size: 100)
    }
    
    func operate() {
        print("operate")
    }
}
```

If I have a subclass named `Car` and create a convenience initializer:

```swift
class Car: Vehicle {
    convenience init(size: Int) {
        self.init(name: "Vehicle", size: size)
    }
}
```

the super class' initializer is made available using `self`.

But, if I want to override the super class' method, it's made available by using `super`:

```swift
class Car: Vehicle {
    // redacted
    
    override func operate() {
        super.operate()
        print("operate a car")
    }
}
```

If the subclass wants to use the inherited method, it's made available by using `self`:

```swift
class Car: Vehicle {
    // redacted

    func drive() {
        self.operate()
        print("drive")
    }
}
```

I understand that class methods are instance methods, meaning `self` refers to the instance of the class. I'm guessing when the subclass inherits the super class' method, it becomes its own instance method.  Why does it not apply to overriding? I'm getting confused between the usage of `self` and `super`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it not apply to overriding?

Well, in this code:

```
class Car: Vehicle {
    // redacted
    
    override func operate() {
        super.operate()
        print("operate a car")
    }
}
```

`self.operate` would refer to the *overridden* method that is in `Car`. In other words, if you called `self.operate()`, it would create infinite recursion. On the other hand, `super.operate` refers to:

```
func operate() {
    print("operate")
}
```

Think of it like this: when you override a method, you kind of "lose" the version of the method that you inherit, and you can only use `super` to access the original in the super class.

Also, no one stops you from doing:

```
class Car: Vehicle {
    func drive() {
        super.operate()
        print("drive")
    }
}
```

It's just that in this case, `super.operate()` and `this.operate()` do exactly the same thing, since `operate` is not overridden in the subclass.

On the other hand, it is illegal to call `super.init` in a convenience initialiser. You must delegate to a `self.init` in a convenience initialiser. And in this case, the super class initialisers are inherited because you don't have any designated initialisers (in general, they aren't inherited!). Read more about initialisers [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This is interesting because I can use `super.operate()` in place of `self.operate()` in any situations within the subclass, even in non-overriding methods, and works just fine. Logging `super.self` and `self` within the subclass both refers to the subclass `Car`.